# How to build SMACK user-space tools for Debian

Tags: debian, security

I have a Debian Buster system installed in virtual machine and want to try out SMACK feature.
For that I have rebuilt the kernel with SMACK options enabled, but there is a problem with SMACK user-space tools. There seems to be no package in Debian for that.

I have checked the source repo for the tools https://github.com/smack-team/smack , but it does not look like something buildable, i.e. there is no Makefile and no configure script inside (only Makefile.am and configure.ac) and no readme file with instructions on how to built it.

Does anybody know how to build it?

Comment: There is a `debian` dir inside, so it looks like you might be able to build this via one of the various tools intended to do the job, for example [gbp-buildpackage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/git-buildpackage/gbp-buildpackage.1.en.html). OTOH, the last commit was made three years ago, so I would be surpised if building would work out of the box.

Comment: "gbp buildpackage" seems to work. After installing git-buildpackage and some dependencies it required for the build, I could build a package with the tools and client library. And I could also install it without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `debian` dir inside, so it looks like you might be able to build this via one of the various tools intended to do the job, for example [gbp-buildpackage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/git-buildpackage/gbp-buildpackage.1.en.html).